# Running out of Connection with WCF service in Azure with SQL Azure

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-servicebus-queues

We have Multi-instance WCF Service (more than 2) which receives requests from ServiceBus Topics (Can have more than 10000 request in subscription).

The nature of the request is that we mainly do inserts in out database. Very minimal processing. Our database is of P1 in SQL Azure.

After sometime, we keep running out of Connection & do receive time outs. I have increased Pool size to 1000 & connection time out to 120 secs. We have checked, & connection pools are definately getting disposed off correctly.

Any Idea where we should start digging?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The higher latencies and the resulting timeouts could be due to reaching the max write capacity of the database.

You can check if this is the case by querying the view sys.dm_db_resource_stats in the database. It shows the resource utilization in percent for the last hour.

If you indeed reach the log write limits, you should consider to upgrade your server to the latest service version (V12) which will give you higher log write rates. If you are already running V12, you may want to consider upgrading to P2.